# Pythonの文字列連結の方法について

Tags: python

+演算子を使って文字列連結すると速度が落ちるということだったので
以下のように、joinをひたすら繰り返すだけのプログラムを試しました

**test.py**

```
test = ''
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
print(test)
```

すると、以下のようなエラーが出ます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emoto\Desktop\test.py", line 10, in <module>
    test = test.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
MemoryError
```

実行環境は、Windows10の64bit、AnacondaPrompt、Pythonのバージョンは3.7です。
+演算子の場合は以下のように文字列連結してもエラーになりません。

**test2.py**

```
test = ""
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
test += "aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"+"aaaa"
print(test)
```

また、以下のようにappendしてからjoinしてみるコードも試してみました。

**test3.py**

```
test = []
test.append(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test.append(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test.append(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
print(''.join(test))
```

すると、以下のようなエラーが出ました。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\emoto\Desktop\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(''.join(test))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

Pythonで複数の文字列を連結するにはどのように書くのがよいのでしょうか？
この例では、"aaaa"という文字列だけを連結していますが
実際の開発中のコードでは、途中でif文やfor文や変数等を組み合わせて文字列連結しています。

Comment: エラーの原因は `test` がリストのリストになっているためです(`print(test)` で確認してみて下さい)。なので、`print(''.join(sum(test, [])))` とすれば文字列の連結になります。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`test3.py`のエラー原因は @metropolis さんコメントで良いとして、`test.py`がエラーになって`test2.py`が正常に動作するのは、その2つの処理が同じ結果では無く`test.py`はそれだけ実際のメモリを使っているからです。
だからテストの方法が悪いわけです。
自分で確認するのは大切だとしても、何をやっているかは意識した方が良いでしょう。

---

`test2.py`では単純に指定された文字列が連結されていくだけですが、`test.py`ではその直前に連結した処理結果が指定された文字列の間に挟まります。
例えば文字の数を減らして、行ごとに文字を変えれば一目瞭然でしょう。`test.py`ではアッという間にサイズが肥大します。
`test.py`簡略化

```
test = ''
test = test.join(["a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a"])
test = test.join(["b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b"])
test = test.join(["c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c","c"])
print(len(test))
```

これで結果の文字数が`3165`
長いので"a"と"b"の連結だけの結果ではこうなります。

```
baaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabaaaaaaaaaaaaaaab
```

`test2.py`簡略化

```
test = ""
test += "a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"+"a"
test += "b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"+"b"
test += "c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"+"c"
print(len(test))
```

こちらは結果の文字数が`45`
同様に"a"と"b"の連結だけの結果ではこうなります。

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

ちなみに`test.py`の元の長さで連結した場合は、8行分だけで`6811334100`=6.34G文字x2byte(Unicode)になります。
9行目で`MemoryError`になりました。

---

`test.py`を`test2.py`と同様の条件にするとしたら、以下のようになるでしょう。
各行毎に完了させる処理で代入となりますが、文字列の連結は`.join`だけで行われます。

```
test = ''
test = ''.join([test,"aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test = ''.join([test,"aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
  ...
```

---

例えばこの辺の記事を参考にしてみるとか。
[文字列連結の常識、joinは本当に速いのか Python3](https://qiita.com/GinRickey/items/d8ed9964820313340a93)
[Pythonの処理速度を上げる方法 その１](https://aqvi.hatenadiary.org/entry/20080411/1207929090)
[Pythonの処理速度を上げる方法　その２](https://aqvi.hatenadiary.org/entry/20080419/1208577161)
[pythonの速度で気にするところ(高速化メモ)](http://nobunaga.hatenablog.jp/entry/2018/03/19/081425)

Answer (score 0):

```
j = ''
test = ''
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
test += j.join(["aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa","aaaa"])
print(test)
```